# Boundary of Open Ball

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Problem:

We want to show that the open ball $B$ centered at zero with radius less than one has a boundary where $x^2+y^2=1$.

Proof?

The closure of a set $A$ is the union of $A$ and its limit points. Set $C=\{(x,y): x^2+y^2=1\}$ is a set containing limit points of the $B$, since any open ball around an element $y$ of $C$ contains points in $B$ not equal to $y$. This means the closure of $B =\{(x,y):x^2+y^2 \leq 1\}$. The boundary of $B$ is the closure of $B$ minus the interior of $B$. Since $B$ is the interior, the boundary is set $C$.

Comment: A ball "centered at zero with radius less than one" does not have the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ as boundary.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good proof, but perhaps you need to more rigorously show that the elements of $C$ are limit points, and that these are the only limit points not in $B$.

Comment: How would I show that the elements in C are the only limit points?

Comment: Take a point not in $B$ or $C$ and show that it has an open neighborhood that misses $B$.